# NSDate Civil Twilight Sunset/Sunrise - Any advice

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am working on a project that includes doing some calculations based on Sunrise / Sunset as well as Civil Sunrise / Civil Sunset (when the sun is 6 degrees below horizon).

I did some searching and see some github projects about this, but they are quite old. Anyone have any advice for doing this? I am not sure of my options and NSDate/NSCalendar doesn't appear to have it built in at all.

Comment: You can calculate it in the code, here you are equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation

Comment: I will look into the equations - at first glance I am scared haha. I am looking for civil sunrise / sunset (dusk) as well, idk if those equations are easily available but will be googling.